# Derivation of differential in relativistic physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, kinematics, reference-frames

I am struggling with derivation of differential $d^3 p$ in relativistic mechanics. In Quantum Electrodynamics: Volume 4 by V. B. Berestetskii, E.M. Lifshitz and L. P. Pitaevskii, Chapter VII, authors derive expression from standard 3D differential:
$$d^3p=p^2d|p|\mathrm d\Omega=|p|d\Omega\frac{\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2d(\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2)}{\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2},$$
with noting that the validity is easily seen with $\epsilon_1^2-m_1^2=\epsilon_2^2-m_2^2=p^2$. It also has to be mentioned that the whole expression is calculated for decay of particle $p$ with mass $m$ into two particles $p_1, p_2$ with energies $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ in the rest frame of decaying particle in which holds : $p_1=-p_2=p$, $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2=m$. I have tried expressing the differential $d|p|$ in terms of $d\epsilon_1$ and $d\epsilon_2$ but I couldn't reproduce their result. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: I don't have this book with me, so can't answer the direct question. But, I do want to say that if you're learn QED from that book, you might want to reconsider your life choices :)

Comment: This book had some explicit QED derivations which I couldn't find in any other book, so I stuck with it unfortunately.

Comment: Edition, page, formula numbers? Your right hand side is proportional to dm?